# HtmlUnit behind proxy

Tags: proxy, htmlunit

I'm using HtmlUnit to get some information from a website. It works when I'm not behind a proxy. When working behind a proxy, I use this code to set the configuration:

```
WebClient webClient = new WebClient(BrowserVersion.FIREFOX_45);
ProxyConfig proxyConfig = new ProxyConfig();
proxyConfig.setProxyAutoConfigUrl(proxyAutoConfigUrl);
webClient.getOptions().setProxyConfig(proxyConfig);
HtmlPage page = webClient.getPage(config.read().getString("homepage.url"));
FrameWindow fw = page.getFrameByName("mainDataIframe");
...
```

But I always get an error:

```
    ERROR AWT-EventQueue-0 com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlPage - Error loading JavaScript from [some website].
java.io.IOException: Unable to download JavaScript from 'some website' (status 404).
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlPage.loadJavaScriptFromUrl(HtmlPage.java:1040)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlPage.loadExternalJavaScriptFile(HtmlPage.java:967)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlScript.executeScriptIfNeeded(HtmlScript.java:352)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlScript$2.execute(HtmlScript.java:238)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlScript.onAllChildrenAddedToPage(HtmlScript.java:257)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HTMLParser$HtmlUnitDOMBuilder.endElement(HTMLParser.java:772)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.endElement(Unknown Source)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HTMLParser$HtmlUnitDOMBuilder.endElement(HTMLParser.java:729)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.cyberneko.HTMLTagBalancer.callEndElement(HTMLTagBalancer.java:1209)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.cyberneko.HTMLTagBalancer.endElement(HTMLTagBalancer.java:1111)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.cyberneko.filters.DefaultFilter.endElement(DefaultFilter.java:207)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.cyberneko.filters.NamespaceBinder.endElement(NamespaceBinder.java:337)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.cyberneko.HTMLScanner$ContentScanner.scanEndElement(HTMLScanner.java:3137)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.cyberneko.HTMLScanner$ContentScanner.scan(HTMLScanner.java:2100)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.cyberneko.HTMLScanner.scanDocument(HTMLScanner.java:927)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.cyberneko.HTMLConfiguration.parse(HTMLConfiguration.java:506)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.cyberneko.HTMLConfiguration.parse(HTMLConfiguration.java:459)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HTMLParser$HtmlUnitDOMBuilder.parse(HTMLParser.java:979)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HTMLParser.parse(HTMLParser.java:241)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HTMLParser.parseHtml(HTMLParser.java:187)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.DefaultPageCreator.createHtmlPage(DefaultPageCreator.java:269)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.DefaultPageCreator.createPage(DefaultPageCreator.java:157)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.loadWebResponseInto(WebClient.java:511)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.getPage(WebClient.java:385)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.getPage(WebClient.java:303)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.getPage(WebClient.java:450)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.getPage(WebClient.java:435)
    at com.bayer.elwasweb.PageReader.messstellenDurchlaufen(PageReader.java:99)
    at com.bayer.elwasweb.PageReader.start(PageReader.java:70)
    at com.bayer.elwasweb.Gui.actionPerformed(Gui.java:211)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
ERROR AWT-EventQueue-0 PageReader - com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.ElementNotFoundException: elementName=[frame or iframe] attributeName=[name] attributeValue=[mainDataIframe]
```

This error never happens without the proxy or in a browser. Is there someone with an idea, why this error happens? Or maybe someone who knows how to find the differences when working behind the proxy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We figured it out! The Exception/Error was misleading..

The error message led us to the conclusion, that that the problem was the not loading JavaScript File which threw the exception. In reality the whole page was not loaded.

The proxy just needed some credentials. We added

```
    final DefaultCredentialsProvider credentialsProvider = 
       (DefaultCredentialsProvider) webClient.getCredentialsProvider();

    credentialsProvider.addCredentials(username, password);
```

to the WebClient configuartaions.